# Removing active notifications on Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g

So I always try Googling first and didn't find anything with any term I used. I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I just got a new phone the other day a Moto G4 Plus with Android 6.0.1 the phone plan I have is a Talk & Text only with Rogers. It includes unlimited MMS as well but I require data on to use this. So I restricted background data and set the data limit to 0 Bytes per month, then enabled data. I can now send the pictures I like.

The issue is that there's now two permanent notifications on the phone that I don't want there. One says "Background data restricted. Touch to remove restriction." and the other "Cellular data limit reached. Data paused for rest of cycle." I want to remove the notifications without removing the restrictions.

If there's a setting I've missed or an app out there that can help with this or a way of doing it without an app, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

With Marshmallow, long pressing the notification will bring up notification settings from there you can disable notifications for the specific app that's causing the persistent notification. Since you are working with the 'system' app you are not able to change any notification settings unless you are rooted. So in short without root permission you will not have access to change notification permissions on any app located in /system/app